# Assigning alternate values to a column based on values of another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My excel looks like this

```
HE123   ON
UE123   ON
eqrq    FALSE
ada FALSE
HE123   OFF
UE123   ON
HE123   OFF
UE123   ON
HE123   OFF
UE123   ON
HE123   OFF
```

What I want is whenever the first two letters of first column are 'HE' or 'UE', it should assign 'ON' and 'OFF' alternatively.

Like:

```
HE123   ON
UE123   OFF
eqrq    FALSE
ada FALSE
HE123   ON
UE123   OFF
HE123   ON
UE123   OFF
HE123   ON
UE123   OFF
HE123   ON
```

I tried this:

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1,2)="UE",LEFT(A1,2)="HE"),IF(MOD(ROW(),2),"OFF","ON"))
```

But this only works if the values are in multiples of 2.

Comment: first of all: vba-tag with no vba included, not a good idea. Secondly this is a table that looks like that?? so if there is "HE" at the beginning there shall be printed "ON" in the next cell and if there is "UE" at the beginnig it would be "OFF"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this standard formula,

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1, 2)={"HE","UE"}), IF(ISEVEN(SUM(COUNTIF(A$1:A1, {"HE*","UE*"}))), "OFF", "ON"))
```

[image: heue_even]

Answer (score 0):

Rethink the question.

If a cell starts with "HE" and the next cell down starts with "UE" then shown "ON".

If a cell starts with "UE" and the previous cell up starts with "HE" then shown "FALSE".

otherwise show "FALSE".

I know you can code this, some hints:

```
   =IF(  AND( LEFT(A1,2)="HE"
             ,LEFT(A2,2)="UE") 
       , IF(MOD(ROW(),2),"OFF","ON")
       , "FALSE"
      )
```